# BOT Framework Advantages of V4 over V3

Tags: c#, botframework

We have a bot in V3 , we are looking to migrate it to V4 , my Manager was asking what is the real advantage we get in V4 that is not there in V3, i tried searching in web but i am not able to find what we get in V4 that is not there in V3.

Can anyone tell me the advantages that are packed with V4?

Thanks.

Comment: [I found this using Google](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/migration/migration-about?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

Comment: If you couldn't find anything in v4 that you didn't get in v3, why *are* you looking to migrate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Amy's link:

> - Introduction of a bot adapter. The adapter is part of the activity processing stack.
> - Refactored state management.
> - A new Dialogs library.
> - Support for ASP.NET Core.

The central idea here is that v4 gives you more flexibility as a developer. The new state management system allows you to choose whether the dialog stack is specific to the user or to the conversation, etc. The new Dialogs library gives you more control how dialogs are started, continued, etc.

I would add a few more items to that list:

- **Parity.** In v3, the .NET SDK operated very differently from the Node SDK. In v4, the SDK is meant to work the same way in each language. This will help you incorporate information from samples you find in languages you're not using.
- **Continued support.** It will certainly be easier to find reliable help with the v4 SDK. The ability to create new v3 bots will [soon be deprecated](https://blog.botframework.com/2019/06/07/v3-bot-broadcast-message/).